# Call a specific function from windows library

Tags: c++, windows

OK so i've heard the "windows.h" is massive and should not be included in the programmes i'm writing at uni, but there is a function in that library that would work well for my robotics module at uni, is there anyway to call the "Sleep()" function only from the library

Code:

```
std::cout<<"Time Elapsed"<<std::endl;
//setDeltaheading to a random direction
desiredState.setVel(0,1.0);
desiredState.setDeltaHeading((rand() % 120) - 45);
// need to wait for turn to complete
state = init;
```

Comment: making programming decisions based on rumor is generally not recommended. You're probably fine including `<windows.h>` and defining `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` and `NOGDI`

Comment: Just having <windows.h> included in a precompled header file (i.e. stdafx.h) eliminates build time concerns. Also, the size of windows.h hasn't kept up with Moore's law. Your PC is many times faster than those when the LEAN_AND_MEAN define was introduced.

Answer (score 2):

You can switch off some of the headers from windows.h by using special macros:

```
   VC_EXTRALEAN
   WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
```

from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/166474

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C++11 then you should use std::thread::sleep_for(xxx);

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
```

More info [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)

Answer (score 0):

Just include `windows.h`. Yes, it's large, and, like any other header, it should only be included if you need it. The size of the header will only affect compilation time (given reasonable optimization options).

If you have access to a C++11 compiler, you could also use [std::this_thread::sleep_for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for).

Answer (score 0):

Then better way is to declare`Sleep` function in your header file. You can copy its definition from the header file.

However, you should not worry about the large header file unless it is slowing down you significantly.